# align text in a tabu-table top-left without tricks

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabu, makecell

I use [tabu](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) and [makecell](https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) to create tables and their content. As many other people I want to align cell content top-left. There are a lot of postings about that topic (with different table environments) on the web. It looks like that there is no easy solution for it. There are only a lot of tricks and workarounds with `\raisebox` etc.

So the question is if there is an easy way or is it not possible with a real solution (means no tricks and workarounds). I imagine a simple `[t,l]` as column option or something like that.

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabu*} spread \textwidth {|X|X|}
    \tabucline{-}
    \makecell{top left}&\makecell{normal\\text\\also top\\left}\\
    \tabucline{-}
\end{tabu*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I remove `makecell` and use of its macro `\makecell{...}` I get result as you desired (text is on the top and justified). Why you need `makecell` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my comment,it is no clear why you use `\makecell{...}`. Top left align is easy to achieve without it. If you still persist to use it, than you need to add option `[tl]` for top align and ragged text an right side:

```
\makecell[tl]{...}
```

MWE, which show result without use of `makecell{..}` (in the first row) and with it (second row) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabu*} spread \textwidth {|X[l]|X|}
    \tabucline{-}
top left longer text top left longer text top left longer text top left longer text top left longer text top left longer text top left longer text top left longer text 
    &   normal\newline text\newline also top\newline left   \\
    \tabucline{-}
\makecell[tl]{top left}
    &   \makecell[tl]{normal\\ text\\ also top\\ left}   \\
    \tabucline{-}
\end{tabu*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great. behave as expcected. I have to check if something in my real code create side affects here. Thank you very much.

Comment: The `t` option is not in the documentation of `makecell`. That was the point.

Comment: It is described on page 3.: *... This will be useful for creation
of multilined cells. This macro allows optional alignment settings.
`\makecell[hvertical or/and horizontal alignmenti]{hcell texti}`
For vertical alignment you use t, b, or c|this letters you usually put in optional argument of tabular or array environments. For horizontal alignment you may use alignment settings like r, l, or c, or more complex, like `{p{3cm}}`. Since this package loads array package, you may use such alignment settings like {>\parindent1cm}p{3cm}}˙`.*

Comment: I should stop doing such things in the middle of the night.