# Trying to get cells containing one line of not text to not move down the text the other cells in the row

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm not really sure how to figure out of someone has asked this before, because I'm not quite sure of the proper terminology.  Sorry if this question is a duplicate.

I am making a tabu with all X cells, and whenever I have to put in something that's not text (like an image, or an array) at the top of a cell, I have to put some pointless text above it, because otherwise, it moves all the text in the other cells in the row down to the level it's at.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
foo
&
$\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{array}$
&
bar
\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: What I don't want]
I want the foo and bar to be at the top of the box.  If I put some text above, and then add an empty line to force a new paragraph, then it works fine:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
foo
&
Some numbers:

$\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{array}$
&
bar
\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: What I do want, sort of.]
I want to know how to make the array (or an image) act the same way when there's nothing above it as when there is.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. - Related (workaround): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318753/124842

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
\begin{array}[t]
```

so the top row rather than the vertical centre of the array is placed on the baseline.

Comment: This only works if the array is by itself in the cell.  If there is text before the array, that text will be at the top of the array as well, which is not what I want.  I want text in a given cell to care *only* about other text in *that* cell and not in any other cell.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if i understood you correctly ... like this?

[image]

i only remove `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=5pt % <-- added
\begin{tabu}{|X |X |X|}
    \hline
foo &   Some numbers:    % <-- this cell is changed (array is removed)

        1 2 3

        4 5 6

        7 8 9   &   bar \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```